# Cannot get the server members by Server#getMembers() although the GUILDS_PRESENCES and GUILDS_MEMBERS intents are enabled

Tags: java, discord

I am using Javacord to write my small admin plugin for my friends' server. Everything was going fine, until I realized I could not get the members of the Server. I was only getting my bot as the only member. Then I searched a little about it, and turns out I needed to turn these intents on. So as you can see on the image, the intents are enabled.[image]
Still, after this, my script only returns my bot as the only member.

What am I doing wrong?
Here's the code for getting the members:
[image: I have tested the code, and it does understand what server it is on.]

Also, the weird thing is that I seem to not have the intents, even after enabling them. This is the list I get on api.getIntents():[image: The last one is DIRECT_MESSAGES]

Comment: Same issue here, i also enabled the Settings

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue as you even after enabling the intents in the Discord Developer Portal.

It turns out that you need to enable the intents in the DiscordApiBuilder:

```
DiscordApi api = new DiscordApiBuilder()
.setToken("your token here")
.setAllIntents() // You can change this depending on which intents you require
.login()
.join();
```

For more info see [this wiki link](https://javacord.org/wiki/basic-tutorials/gateway-intents.html#setting-intents)

Comment: Hey there! Thanks for you suggestion, but sadly although not mentioned in the original post, I have already tried using the intent related functions of DiscordApiBuilder. Enabling all of the intents did not enable the priviled ones, while setting a specific intent froze my login process, so the bot did not login.

Comment: Oh sorry about that. Hopefully you manage to resolve your issue!